# SUM of columns duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation

I have table as below

```
DATE                | JOB_ID    |Name       | Count
--------------------|-----------|-----------|--------
01-JAN-18 01:02:41  | JOB_1     | weight    | 200
01-JAN-18 01:02:41  | JOB_1     | weight    | 200
01-JAN-18 01:02:42  | JOB_1     | weight    | 200
01-JAN-18 01:02:43  | JOB_1     | weight    | 200
01-JAN-18 01:02:43  | JOB_1     | weight    | 200
02-JAN-18 01:02:44  | JOB_2     | weight    | 200
02-JAN-18 01:02:45  | JOB_2     | weight    | 200
01-JAN-18 01:03:16  | JOB_1     | baseball  | 192
01-JAN-18 01:11:15  | JOB_1     | hanescom  | 37
01-JAN-18 01:11:15  | JOB_1     | hanescom  | 200
01-JAN-18 01:11:16  | JOB_1     | hanescom  | 200
01-JAN-18 01:11:17  | JOB_1     | hanescom  | 200
01-JAN-18 01:11:17  | JOB_1     | hanescom  | 200
01-JAN-18 01:11:18  | JOB_1     | hanescom  | 200
03-JAN-18 01:11:25  | JOB_3     | hanescom  | 200
03-JAN-18 01:11:26  | JOB_3     | hanescom  | 200
03-JAN-18 01:11:26  | JOB_3     | hanescom  | 200
01-JAN-18 01:11:27  | JOB_1     | hanescom  | 189
01-JAN-18 01:11:28  | JOB_1     | wwbundle  | 200
01-JAN-18 01:11:29  | JOB_1     | wwbundle  | 200
01-JAN-18 01:11:29  | JOB_1     | wwbundle  | 200
01-JAN-18 01:11:30  | JOB_1     | wwbundle  | 200
```

I want to get below results,

```
DATE                | JOB_ID    |Name       | sum(Count)
--------------------|-----------|-----------|--------
01-JAN-18           |JOB_1      |weight     | 1000
02-JAN-18           |JOB_2      |weight     |  400 
01-JAN-18           |JOB_1      |baseball   |  192
01-JAN-18           |JOB_1      |hanescom   | 1226
03-JAN-18           |JOB_3      |hanescom   |  600
01-JAN-18           |JOB_1      |wwbundle   |  800
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? Include your query.

Comment: i am new to complex sql queries. tried below but not given expected results,
select distinct to_char(date, 'DD-MON-YY') as date,JOB_ID,name,sum(count) from Table_A

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What did you try? What problem did you encounter? Include your query.

Comment: tried this 
select distinct to_char(date, 'DD-MON-YY') as date,JOB_ID,name,sum(count) from Table_A

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use date format method of sql to get the desired result

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date_column, JOB_ID, Name, sum("count")
  FROM tab
 GROUP BY date_column, JOB_ID, Name;

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle, so this is not valid syntax.

Comment: Even cannot group by `date_column`, since it's an alias.

Comment: How can an answer with an invalid syntax be accepted?

Comment: i think its not much about syntax its about the approach

Comment: In mysql you can groupby alias

Comment: @PrateekJain - but the question is about Oracle RDBMS, not MySQL. And if you ignore that  (which you shouldn't) then the approach is basically the same as the earlier answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing but a simple grouping as follows :

```
SELECT trunc("date") as "Date", JOB_ID as "Job ID", 
       Name as "Name", sum("count") as "Sum of Counts"
  FROM tab
 GROUP BY trunc("date"), JOB_ID, Name;
```

where `date` and `count` are *reserved keywords*, and should be wrapped in double quotes.

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/571ff/1)

Comment: i have tried this and its worked fine :) 

SELECT to_char(date,'DD-MON-YY') as date,JOB_ID, name, sum(count) from Table group by to_char(date,'DD-MON-YY'),job_id,name;

Comment: @Sum - using `trunc()` is cleaner IMO as it preserves the data type. You can still explicitly format the date in the result set with `to_char(trunc("date"), 'DD-MON-RR')` in the select list only, leaving plain `trunc("date")` in the group-by. Also, be careful with `MON` as it relies on session NLS settings.